# Cannot edit regional settings in drupal 7

Tags: i18n-l10n

I cannot edit any of setting presented in regional settings category under admin/config/regional/settings. Whenever I for example remove tick from "Users may set their own time zone" and click save the page basically reloads with the same settings as they were before change.

Any ideas on how to fix this or overcome the issue? My main goal is to disable locale settings section in the /user/edit page.

Comment: There is some kind of error in your Drupal instance, that should be working. It is very hard anyone but you to make the debug. I suggest you take a look at your PHP and Apache errors. Also, enable the "Database logging" (dblog) module and look for error messages there (admin/reports/dblog).